# Java Regex: Matching a string between 2 colons

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a Java regex that will find all the strings between 2 `:`. If the string between the characters has whitespaces, line endings or tabs, it should be ignored. Empty strings are also ignored. `_` are ok! The group can either include the enclosing `:` or not.

Here are a few tests and the expected groups:

```
"test :candidate: test" => ":candidate:"
"test :candidate: test:" => ":candidate:"
"test :candidate:_test:" => ":candidate:", ":_test:"
"test :candidate::test" => ":candidate:"
"test ::candidate: test" => ":candidate:"
"test :candidate_: :candidate: test" => ":candidate_:", ":candidate:"
"test :candidate_:candidate: test" => ":candidate_:", ":candidate:"
```

I've tested a lot of regex and these ones almost work:

```
":(\\w+):"
":[^:]+:"
```

I still have a problem when the 2 groups "share" a colon:

```
"test :candidate_: :candidate: test" => ":candidate_:", ":candidate:" // OK
"test :candidate_:candidate: test" => ":candidate_:" // ERROR! :(
```

It seems like the first group "consumes" the second colon and that the matcher can't find the second string I expected.

Can someone point me in the right direction to solve this problem?
Can you also elaborate on why the matcher "consumes" the colon?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you consider to process the string differently? Instead of using matchers and so forth most of the lifting can be done with String#split

Comment: Yes, I thought about `split()` but I wanted to understand how to do it with a regex. I think I will use this method if I can't find a regex solution.

Comment: Which regex method are you using? You need to capture every : : delimited region inside of a match group, right?

Comment: @PatrickCollins I need either both `:` or none.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a Positive Lookahead for capturing to get the overlapping matches.

```
(?=(:\\w+:))
```

**Note**: You can access your match result by refering to capturing group `#1` ( [Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bC2qK5/1) )

Comment: I was thinking more about `:\\w+(?=(:))` but this will also do the trick. +1 but you probably should be more explicit that matched part will be in group 1.

Comment: @VincentDurmont Mine solution would require combining match from group 0 and group 1 (if you also want to include last `:` in match). In this solution you just need to use group 1. But if you don't want to include `:` in match then you can just use `(?<=:)\\w+(?=:)` and get result from group 0.

Comment: @pshemo or there's always the one-line ninja version (below) :)

Answer (score 4):

How about `String.split()`?

```
String invalidChars = " |\t|\r|\f|\n"; // regex for invalid characters

String testStr = "test :candidate:_test:";
String[] parts = testStr.Split(":");
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String part : parts)
{
    if (part.matches(invalidChars) || part.isEmpty()) continue;
    results.add(part);
}
```

`results` should contain `candidate` and `_test`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought about `split()` but I was wondering if there was an easier solution with a regex.

Comment: @VincentDurmont You should look at `hwnd`'s answer. Although I haven't tested it, it looks correct as well.

Comment: You can simplify the code (avoid the inner for) using String#matches to find out whether there are any invalid characters.

Comment: I would change .equals("") for .isEmpty()

Comment: @ValentinRuano Edited. (I hope it's correct, since I haven't been able to test this at all as I don't have any Java compiler near me.)

Comment: @PatrickCollins What makes you say that regex is not the right tool? (just trying to understand how it works)

Comment: @VincentDurmont Although your question was directed at Patrick Collins, I will answer this one too: I believe that regexes are not necessary here because there is a better solution (in my opinion): `split`. I would rather use something other than regex, because in my experience regexes can get very complicated to fathom, while code like that in my answer remains understandable.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of regex replace to clean up the input, then split can get the whole task done in just one line:

```
String[] terms = input.replaceAll("(?s)^.*?:|:[^:]*$", "").split("(?s):([^:]*\\s[^:]*:)?");
```

This works for all your edge cases, by:

- removing input from head and tail (including the leading/trailing colons)
- splitting on a colon, optionally followed by junk and another colon
- the "dotall" flag `(?s)` makes it work over multiple lines

---

Here's some test code:

```
String[] inputs =  {
        "foo:target1:bar",
        "foo:target1:target2:bar",
        "foo:target1:target2:target3:bar",
        "foo:target1:junk junk:target2:bar" ,
};
for (String input : inputs) {
    String[] terms = input.replaceAll("(?s)^.*?:|:[^:]*$", "").split("(?s):([^:]*\\s[^:]*:)?");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(terms));
}
```

Output:

```
[target1]
[target1, target2]
[target1, target2, target3]
[target1, target2]
```

Comment: I am not sure if this works as OP wants since `target2` is ignored (or actually part of `.split(":(.*:)?");` so it is consumed leaving us with only `target1` and `target3`.

Comment: @Pshemo yes - that's what this does. the example input is what this code *doesn't* handle. It does handle `"foo:target1:junk:target2:bar"` and `"foo:target1:target2:bar"`

Comment: If I understand OP correctly `junkxxx` is actually correct value because there is no whitespaces inside so IMHO it should be included in result (but I may be mistaken, OP would have to judge this solution).

Comment: @Pshemo I knew it could be done in one line (see edit). Thanks for the coaching :)